# How can I align a photo with a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot in R several panels with data measured along a sediment core (see image below). Next to the plots, I want to add a photo of that sediment core, aligned to the exact y coordinates as the plots (to be able to identify if a certain layer in the photo corresponds to a peak in some element in the plot).

The piece of code below produces de multipanel plot plus the photo (see below as well). As you can see using the tape measure in the photo, the y coordinates of the plots do not match the coordinates of the photo.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(1,4), oma = c(5,4,2,0) + 0.1, mar = c(0,0,4,1) + 0.1, pch = 20)

plot(y = -curian3_scores$Sample, x = curian3_scores$RC1, xaxt = "n", type = "o", pch =16, ylab = "", xlab = "", lwd = 1.5, col = "blue", ylim = c(-1197.744, -40), cex.axis = 1.2)
axis(3, cex.axis = 1.2)
mtext(side = 3, text = var.PC1, line = 2.2, cex = 0.9)
mtext(side = 2, text = "Depth (mm)", line = 3, cex = 0.9)

plot(y = -curian3_scores$Sample, x = curian3_scores$RC2, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", type = "o", ylab = "", xlab = "", lwd = 1.5, col = "red", ylim = c(-1197.744, -40), cex.axis = 1.2)
axis(3, cex.axis = 1.2)
mtext(side = 3, text = var.PC2, line = 2.2, cex = 0.9)

plot(y = -curian3_scores$Sample, x = curian3_scores$RC3, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", type = "o", ylab = "", xlab = "", lwd = 1.5, col = "darkgreen", ylim = c(-1197.744, -40), cex.axis = 1.2)
axis(3, cex.axis = 1.2)
mtext(side = 3, text = var.PC3, line = 2.2, cex = 0.9)

# Charge the image as an R object with the "JPEG" package
library(jpeg)
my_image=readJPEG("~/Documents/FEINA/POSTDOCTORAT/RESILCOAST/ARTICLES/Carbon_persistence/Data_mining/CoreScanner/Core_Images_for_R/CURIAN3a_8.jpg")
# Set up a plot area with no plot
plot(y = -curian3_scores$Sample, x = curian3_scores$RC3, type = "n", axes = F, ylab = "", xlab = "")
# Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box, and draw it
lim <- par()
rasterImage(my_image, xleft = lim$usr[1], ybottom = lim$usr[3], xright = lim$usr[2], ytop = lim$usr[4])

par(op)
```

[image]

Any ideas to make the photo's and plots' coordinates to match? If the ylim in each plot worked, I think this would be it... however, I think they're overruled for some reason...